# How to import functions in Playwright component tests?

Tags: svelte, playwright, sveltekit

I am trying to setup Playwright [component tests](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-components) for my Svelte/SvelteKit projects.

I would like to test my components using shared mock data. That is, I have functions that return a known state of mock data, and I want to set this data is props for various components under test.

But this is currently not possible. I have to copy and paste these same functions in to every test file.

This is a [known limitation](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-components#q-i-cant-import-anything-other-than-the-components-from-tsxjsxcomponent-files), but the solution is not very well explained, or demonstrated, and I've not been able to figure out how to do this in my project.

What I've tried:

- Import the function(s)
- Move the function(s) to the same directory to import
- Expose the function(s) in the svelte components context="module" section

A solution + examples of how to do this would be MUCH appreciated.

Comment: I'm also looking into Playwright component testing with Svelte/SvelteKit. I'm currently struggling, simply because I write in Typescript. Do you have a solution for this issue? https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/19970 (hopefully I can help find a solution for your issue also)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not having this problem, but it seems like you were able to resolve that problem in your GitHub issue.

FYI, I am not having this problem, but my configuration does not use their solution.

Comment: Using a relative import with the file extension works, feels a bit messy though. E.g. `import { x } from ../path/to/mockData.js`